# How to log AWS SES event details

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-cloudwatch

For some reason I'm having trouble connecting the dots on how to do what seems pretty simple.

**How do I log all e-mail sent through the AWS Simple Email Service with specific message details?**

That log, at the very minimum, needs to contain the IP address of the sending server. But, I really need the `TO` address as well. Backstory - we have several servers that utilize this service, and when one of them acts up and starts sending thousands of e-mails we get alerts through Cloudwatch monitoring - but no way to find out what server is actually sending them.

Immediately, upon research, you find evidence of people really wanting this feature and it not being available. However, newer articles suggest this is possible.

Ideally, I have tried to use Event Publishing to Cloudwatch as described in these two articles:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-using-event-publishing.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-add-event-destination-cloudwatch.html

- I created a new SES configuration set.
- I added a cloudwatch destination to this configuration set.
- I specified Event Types of Sends; Rejects; Bounces; Complaints; Deliveries; Rendering Failures
- I chose Value Source of `Message Tag` with Name of `ses:source-ip` and Default Value of `source-ip`.

After some time, no events are published to Cloud Watch.

The documentation just isn't very clear on this whole process, and never gets down the actual details with examples.

There is some suggestion that I might have to add headers to our outgoing e-mail to track, but other suggestions that there are defaults, and that I don't actually have to modify our sending behavior.

> **Fine-grained** – These metrics are categorized by email characteristics
>   that you define using message tags. To publish these metrics to
>   CloudWatch, you must set up event publishing with a CloudWatch event
>   destination and specify a configuration set when you send an email.
>   You can also specify message tags or use auto-tags that Amazon SES
>   automatically provides.

There is also some documentation about using Kinesis Firehose as a destination and it shows examples of very detailed message info - which is exactly what I would love to have: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-retrieving-firehose-examples.html#event-publishing-retrieving-firehose-send

I just don't know which direction to go here and how to set this up.

**I need the simplest way to log what seems like basic SES diagnostic information and use it for troubleshooting purposes later.** It's hard to believe this information isn't just readily available in the AWS console somewhere.

Comment: Did you resolve this one? I'm looking at the same thing now and not making much progress

Comment: @Elliveny I have not come back to this. But I do understand the limitations better. You can make progress if, and this is a big “if,” you are willing and able to make sure all messages you send through ses are tagged with certain message headers. You will not be able to do any of these logging features without that. There is no “default.” “...you must...specify a configuration set when you send an email.”

Answer (score 1):

Did you already see the tutorial ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-tutorials.html

I hope that could help ya

Answer (score 0):

I've commented on your post first and then suddenly, after whole day of testing, realisation occured in my head.

This realisation came from the AWS [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/introducing-sending-metrics/). Heading "How do message tags work?"

TLDR is, auto-tags are getting applied either if you are using AWS SES `SendEmail/SendRawEmail` API or adding `X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET: CONFIGURATION-SET-NAME` header when using SMTP credentials.

Unfortunately for us there is no cheap way of having this kind of detail logged = ).

Kinesis streaming seems like the only option.